# Light mesh with specific light three js

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, light

I have a scene with a couple of objects and some objects in these case the spheres i want to be affected by the lights with the colors pink and blue. 
But i also have a tube geometry that should only be affected by a white light, without being affected by the pink and blue lights.

See image below for demonstration of the problem: 
What happens now: 
[image]
But i want the tube not to be pink and blue but gray: 
[image]

Currently i do this with a `meshBasicMaterial` but that prevents the the tube from looking 3D.

So how do i create this gray tube with a `MeshLambertMaterial` that is not affected by the pink and blue lights?

See code below for how i generate my scene now:

```
# Generating of spheres:
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var SphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(2, 20, 20);
        var SphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0xffffff });
        var Sphere = new THREE.Mesh(SphereGeometry, SphereMaterial);
        Sphere.position.set(i * 7 -14, 0 + Math.random() * 5 - 2.5, 2);
        spheresArray.push(Sphere);
        scene.add(Sphere);
    }

#Generation of tubes:
for (var i = 0; i < CurvesArray.length; i++) {
        var geometry = new THREE.TubeGeometry( CurvesArray[i], 20, 0.5, 8, false );
        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xe3e3e3 } );
        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        scene.add( mesh );
    }

#and these are my lights:
var spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight( 0xff00cc );
    spotLight.position.set( -10, 3, 30, 100 );
    lightsArray.push(spotLight);
    scene.add(spotLight);

    var spotLight2 = new THREE.SpotLight( 0xaa99cc );
    spotLight2.position.set( 5, 15, 10, 100 );
    lightsArray.push(spotLight2);
    scene.add(spotLight2);

    var spotLight3 = new THREE.SpotLight( 0x0022bb );
    spotLight3.position.set( 2, -15, 10, 100 );
    lightsArray.push(spotLight3);
    scene.add(spotLight3);

    var light = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x5f5f5f );
    scene.add( light );
```

If any additional information is required or something is not clear let me know so i can clarify!

Comment: AFAIK, it's not possible so far. Only if you write custom shaders for spheres and tubes. Read this [forum topic](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/layers-and-lights/4155?u=prisoner849).

Comment: @prisoner849 ok thats a bit of a shame :( Did u managed to get some sort of shader working to get the desired results of selective lightning?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use layers: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.layers

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/mmalex/1xr356zf/

1. Lights will affect only objects that share same layer.
2. Camera will see objects that belong to the layer, where camera belongs to.

Assign your objects and lights layers:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var SphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(2, 20, 20);
    var SphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0xffffff });
    var Sphere = new THREE.Mesh(SphereGeometry, SphereMaterial);
    Sphere.position.set(i * 7 -14, 0 + Math.random() * 5 - 2.5, 2);

    // set layers to Spheres
    Sphere.layers.set(i%3); // <<=== check here!
    spheresArray.push(Sphere);
    scene.add(Sphere);
}
```

Assign layers to lights:

```
var spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight( 0xff00cc );
spotLight.position.set( -10, 3, 30, 100 );
spotLight.layers.set(0); // << === layer 0 is by default
lightsArray.push(spotLight);
scene.add(spotLight);

var spotLight2 = new THREE.SpotLight( 0xaa99cc );
spotLight2.position.set( 5, 15, 10, 100 );
spotLight2.layers.set(1);  // << === layer 1 set to spotLight2
lightsArray.push(spotLight2);
scene.add(spotLight2);

var spotLight3 = new THREE.SpotLight( 0x0022bb );
spotLight3.position.set( 2, -15, 10, 100 );
spotLight3.layers.set(2);  // << === layer 2 set to spotLight3
lightsArray.push(spotLight3);
scene.add(spotLight3);
```

And render layers one by one:

```
let animate = function() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  controls.update();

  renderer.autoClear = true;
  camera.layers.set(0); // << == switch camera between layers
  renderer.render(scene, camera);

  renderer.autoClear = false; // don't remove previous layer results

  camera.layers.set(1); // << == switch camera between layers
  renderer.render(scene, camera);

  camera.layers.set(2); // << == switch camera between layers
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
};
```